VBA excel error no data supplied for parameters in prepared statement using odbc driver 8.4
I have code in VBA of excel that connects to a mysql database and runs a stored procedure using adodb.command.
This has always worked with no problems. However, when I updated my ODBC driver for MySql from 8.0 to 8.4, I suddenly started getting errors of
"...no data supplied for parameters in prepared statement"
I have stepped through the code and values are definitely being passed. It is successfully connecting to the database as well. If I run a sql query directly, there is no problem. Only when I use the command object with a stored procedure does this occur.
Please see code below:
    Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
    
    With cmd
        .ActiveConnection = cnnXLW
        .CommandText = "xxxx"  'correct name is supplied here
        .CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pVersionNum", adVarChar, adParamInput, 10, VersionNum)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("pClientUID", adVarChar, adParamInput, 20, ClientUID)
        Set rs = .Execute()
    End With

Thanks in advance for any help.

Unfortunately not. Have had to go back to an earlier version of the ODBC driver
